# Microsoft Visio 2010 Tables and Relationships

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, visio

I have created Database Relationship Diagrams using Microsoft Visio 2010, things have been well - My Question? 
Is there a way to convert these tables into sql codes, I mean rather than writing every single code. I am looking for any possible way to generate these codes from my exciting tables.

Thanks for any help in advance :-)

Comment: You can find your answer here http://bit.ly/1n3xAlD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GUI tools in Access to re-create the ERDs. It's pretty much the equivalent of using a WYSIWYG for building websites. 
I've scoured the internet and have found nothing successful by means of just generating code by loading an ERD from Visio into your dbms.

Comment: thanks for help - but where to find the right place to download GUI tools because it seems hard to find it as i tried my best

Comment: Microsoft Access is a GUI tool. You can use the user interface (click buttons and type) to populate your table information, etc. It pretty much creates the database for you as long as you know what your tables are, their records, etc.